# How do I get information from this page, that isn't in the HTML code

Tags: php, html-parsing

http://www.aliexpress.com/item/NEW-7-Android-2-3-256MB-DDR2-4GB-NAND-Flash-7-inch-tablet-pc/498159194.html - I got this link

Here you can see a buttons: bundle, color

If you click some of them the price will change, but the question is how can I parse that behaviour to my page via php?

The problem is that I can't understand where is javascript code that executes this, or how to find it, maybe someone got ideas about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspecting that page's source code I can see that the `skuProducts` variable in javascript contains this information encoded into a JSON-string. You can't really run this javascript code on your webserver, so you'll have to devise another way to get that variable's value - and then you can use `json_decode()` to get the contents.

Note that changing the amount of items results in an AJAX call to a shipping costs calculator. You could probably simulate that, but I'm not sure that webshop would like that (and it might be illegal).

Comment: Far from illegal. Accessing a publicly available webpage (excluding regional restrictions) is not illegal.

Comment: Using computational resources to then display on your own website isn't though. Using, without permission, information made public in any kind of database for commercial purposes also is illegal in many countries (e.g. Dutch Databankenwet, artikel 5).